# How to remove red underlines at Codeigniter 3 on session, model?

Tags: php, codeigniter, visual-studio-code

[Visual studio code show syntax error in Codeigniter 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8lx6.png)

Visual studio code is showing syntax error on session and model those are already injected on the controller. It did not happen before. Note: I use PHP Intelephense extension.

How can I get rid of it?

I was injecting models into controller with this `$this->load->model('cart_model');` Previously, no underline at `cart_model` after `$this->` when `$old_cart_data = $this->cart_model->get_all(['user_id' => $user_id]);`

Answer (score 0):

Write this comment above your controller

```
/**
 * @property Cart_model $cart_model
 */
class MiController extends CI_Controller {
    // Your code
}
```